# Columnas dinámicas Exceljs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, excel, typescript

Comunidad, saludos.
Sigo en mi aprendizaje de ExcelJS y nodejs y ahora me topé con el siguiente problema:
Una función obtiene las columnas de forma dinámica de varias partes de mi aplicación y filtra las vacías de las que no y devuelve un arreglo. La función es la siguiente:

```
const objectsFromCols = () => {
    let cols = dt.props.columnas.filter((columna) => columna.exportable === undefined || columna.exportable !== false);
    cols = cols.filter((col) => col !== undefined);
    let values = dt.props.value.map((registro) => {
        let registroExport = {}
        cols.map((columna) => {
            if (columna.field.indexOf('.') == -1) {
                if (registro[columna.field] === true || registro[columna.field] === false) {
                    if (registro[columna.field] === false) {
                        registroExport[columna.field] = 'No';
                    } else {
                        registroExport[columna.field] = 'Sí';
                    }
                } else {
                    registroExport[columna.field] = registro[columna.field];
                }

            } else {
                let anidado = columna.field.split('.');
                if (registro[anidado[0]] !== null && registro[anidado[0]] !== undefined) {
                    registroExport[columna.header] = registro[anidado[0]][anidado[1]];
                } else {
                    registroExport[columna.header] = null;
                }
            }

        })
        return registroExport;
    })
    return values;
}
```

Con ExcelJS deseo obtener los headers de dichas columnas pero no sé cómo obtener el header o el key de forma dinámica ya que los valores de éstos, cambian dependiendo de la tabla que reciba la función `objectsFromCols`. Ya intenté con algo así pero me arroja indefinido:

```
ws.columns=[
        {header: columnas.header, key: columnas.field, width: 25}
    ];
```

A continuación, un resultado de la función `objectsFromCols`:
[image: Resultado de objectsFromCols]

Que es un arreglo de muchos arreglos que contienen sus propios headers. Estos headers son sólo un ejemplo, pues esta función recibe arreglos de arreglos con nombres distintos.
¿Alguien tiene alguna recomendación? De antemano agradezco las respuestas como siempre, comunidad.

Comment: Object.keys podría servir?

Comment: ¿Podrías ahondar más en eso? Por favor. Sigo aprendiendo react y nodejs, por lo que hay cosas que todavía no conozco.

Comment: `Object.keys` te ayuda a obtener el nombre de la propiedad de un objeto, por ejemplo si tienes un `{ name: 'Paulo', age: 31 }`, con *Object.keys* te devolvería `['name', 'age']`. No sé si se ajusta a lo que necesitas. Podrías incluir el resultado de la función para tener un mejor contexto también

Comment: Lo que sucede es que esa función de "ObjectsFromCols recibe un DataTable que viene de otra página donde puede traer diferente número y nombre de columnas. Por eso no puedo declarar un {name, age, etc}

Comment: Insisto en que podría servir mi alternativa. Como te comenté, incluye en tu pregunta lo que devuelve esa función y yo te armo un ejemplo práctico 

Comment: Listo, ya edité la pregunta agregando lo que devuelve la función.